# Regex pattern in Python for Malaysian phone number (to be used in Power BI)

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I need to create a regex pattern in python (to be used on Power BI) that meets the following criteria in order to validate Malaysian phone numbers:

1. Accept mobile number with Malaysia country code 60 - *60123455678*
2. Accept + sign in front of country code  - *+60123455678*
3. Accept mobile number without leading zero  - *123455678*
4. Accept mobile number with leading zero - *0123455678*
5. Accept length of mobile number if service provider is "111" -*01113455678*
6. Accept only numeric characters

Anyone can help on this? Appreciate in advance.

This is what I have tried so far which is to validate:

1. Accept mobile number without leading zero
2. Accept mobile number with leading zero
3. Accept mobile number with country code [but not specific to Malaysia country code]

```
dataset['Validity_Mobile_Number'] = 
dataset['MobileNumber'].apply(lambda x: 'Valid' if pd.isnull(x) or
pd.Series([True if pd.Series(x).apply(str).str.contains('1[0-9]{8}|11[0-9]{8}|[0-9]{8}').any() else False]).bool() or
                                                          else 'Invalid')
```

Comment: The given rules for the phone number are too imprecise. Are the numbers without leading zero or country code always 9 digits long? Do they always begin with `1`? Or (according to the regex) is it a `1` or `11` followed by 8 digits? Can the first of the 8 digits be a `1` or a `0`? Regarding "5." what means "accept length" and why is the digit `2` missing in the number?

Comment: Not to mention that your criteria 2 and 6 are contradictory... If it's supposed to be only numeric characters, why is `+` acceptable? Please not only be more precise, but also analyse your requirements before you'll submit the edit.

Comment: From what I understood (your rules indeed lack precision), this might work (you'll have to test it though): `'\+?0*(?:60)?\d{8}|0*111\d+'`

Answer (score 1):

Since - as the commentators pointed out - your question lacks precision, I searched for the requirements of Malaysian mobile phone numbers and created this solution.

```
import re

def is_valid_malaysian_mobile(number):
    pattern = re.compile(r'^(?:(?:\+60|0060)(?:[1]|[0]?[1])[ -]?|[0])[0-9]{2}[ -]?[0-9]{3,4}[ -]?[0-9]{3,4}$')
    return bool(pattern.match(number))

# Test cases
valid_numbers = [
    '+60123456789',
    '+601234567890',
    '0060123456789',
    '00601234567890',
    '0123456789',
    '01234567890',
    '+60-123-456-789',
    '+60 123 456 789',
    '012-3456-7890',
    '012 3456 7890',
    '+60(0)123456789'
]

invalid_numbers = [
    '+6012345678',    # too short
    '+6012345678901', # too long
    '+601123456789',  # invalid mobile prefix
    '+61123456789',   # incorrect country code
    '+60123456789a',  # contains a letter
]

# Testing valid numbers
for number in valid_numbers:
    assert is_valid_malaysian_mobile(number), f"Failed: {number} should be valid"

# Testing invalid numbers
for number in invalid_numbers:
    assert not is_valid_malaysian_mobile(number), f"Failed: {number} should be invalid"

print("All tests passed!")
```

**Allowed**

- Country code: +60 or 0060
- Local format: leading 0 without the country code
- Mobile prefix: 3-digit number starting with 1 (e.g., 010, 011, 012, 013, 014, 016, 017, 018, 019)
- Phone number length: 7 or 8 digits after the mobile prefix
- Separators: dashes (-) or spaces between parts of the number
- Parentheses: optional leading 0 within parentheses (e.g., +60(0)123456789) when the country code is used

**Not allowed**

- Incorrect country code (e.g., +61)
- Invalid mobile prefix (e.g., 015, 020)
- Too short or too long phone numbers
- Non-numeric characters, excluding allowed separators and parentheses
- Other separators or formatting not listed in the "Allowed" section

Please check if these lists for completeness and comment if something is missing or wrong.